# Compare files in a directory with content in other files

Tags: linux, shell

I want to compare files of a directory with content in other file .i.e I have a folder(A) that contains multiple files. and I have a file(final.txt) in other folder that contains name of files present in "A" .
All I want is, compare filename of files present in the directory A within the file "final.txt". if file name is already in final.txt then skip that file else copy the file to "B" directory from "A."

Answer (score 3):

[`rsync`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) to the rescue:

```sh
rsync -rv --exclude-from=final.txt a/ b/
```

This copies all the files from directory `a` to directory `b` if they aren't listed in `final.txt` (Or if they already exist in `b`)